# Change darktable base directory

Tags: 18.04, darktable

I am trying to change the base directory in darktable for when I import photos.

I want to save them to a hard drive on the same computer. I reallocated (possibly wrong term) the drive so that it would appear as "HDD" next to "home".

The file path when I click and drag is: file:///HDD/Photos

It keeps making new directories in the "HOME" folder (and other places depending on what I type).

Comment: I moved the HDD folder within the home folder, and made the Photos folder within that the default Pictures folder. Both darktable and Shotwell are having a tough time importing to a separate HDD. Could it be because of the file system? Does the importing folder have to be on the same drive at the OS?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the format of the drive. I was trying to save files using darktable and Shotwell to a NTFS drive, which can be read from, but not written to in these programs. They worked fine with an external formatted to exFAT, so I am moving things around and reformatting the internal drive.